# LINQ - Nested Count Question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have the following code for Customers and their orders. I want to list all the customerID and the corresponding count of orders. How do I achieve it using LINQ?

Note: I am new to LINQ and var.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<Order> orderListForCus1 = new List<Order>();
    Order ord1 = new Order(1, new DateTime(2011, 9, 1));
    Order ord2 = new Order(1, new DateTime(2011, 8, 1));
    orderListForCus1.Add(ord1);
    orderListForCus1.Add(ord2);

    Customer cus1 = new Customer();
    cus1.CustomerID = 1;
    cus1.OrderList = orderListForCus1;


    List<Customer> customerRecordsBook = new List<Customer>();
    customerRecordsBook.Add(cus1);


    var orderCounts = from c in customerRecordsBook
                      select new { c.CustomerID, OrderCount = c.OrderList.Count() };



}
```

Comment: You already have that.  What are you asking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.
You can loop over your anonymously-typed objects just like any other objects:

```
foreach (var o in orderCounts) {
    Response.Write(o.CustomerID + ": " + o.OrderCount + " orders");
}
```

Note that `o` must be declared as `var`, since the type has no name that you can use.

---

In your case, you don't actually need LINQ; you can just use the `List<T>` directly:

```
foreach (var c in customerRecordsBook) {
    Response.Write(c.CustomerID + ": " + c.OrderList.Count + " orders");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already done that, and now you can iterate throught the result as:

```
foreach(var item in orderCounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", item.CustomerID, item.OrderCount);
}
```

Comment: `new { c.CustomerID, ...` is implicitly named.

Comment: @SLaks: Oh yeah... removed that part from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer based on your comment:

You don't need to do the `from .. select` at all.  Just iterate `customerRecordsBook` and write what you want:

```
foreach (var c in customerRecordsBook)
{
    Response.Write(string.Format("ID: {0}, Orders: {1}<br />",
        c.CustomerID, c.OrderList.Count);
}
```

Or, better yet, use a control such as a Repeater or GridView, and set customerRecordsBook as the Datasource.

Comment: I like learning new things on SO.  Never knew that shortcut.  Thanks!